# how do I rotate a view in iOS objectiv-c?

Tags: objective-c, uikit, screen, orientation

I'm working on an old objective-c project. I have a requirement to run one of the views in landscape mode. The view is presented (not sure if this is relevant jut to let you know). I have:

- the deployment info on "General" tab check all possible orientations
- in  application delegate supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow ->  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
- requires full screen checked

Problem:
- none of the following methods are calling:

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}
```

```
- the view is stay in portrait mode
```

I'm copying here my viewdidappear function:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if (@available(iOS 16.0, *)) {
        [self setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations];
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    
    if (@available(iOS 16.0, *)) {
        [self setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations];
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
   
    UIWindowScene *windowScene = self.view.window.windowScene;
    if (!windowScene) { return; }
    UIWindowSceneGeometryPreferences *preferences = [[UIWindowSceneGeometryPreferencesIOS alloc] initWithInterfaceOrientations:UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight];
    [windowScene requestGeometryUpdateWithPreferences:preferences errorHandler:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        // Handle error here
    }];
}
```

I got the error that landscape right orientation is not supported, only portrait.

Any idea how to fix it?

Thank you,
Geanni